# Excel - Auto fill repetitive date range of same 2 months each year

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create cells in excel for Jun and Nov of each year starting in 1993. I tried entering the first 3 years then dragging the cells but Excel doesn't recognize the pattern.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Jun-93 is on A2, a workaround will be to use this formula:

```
=IF(MONTH(A2)=6,EDATE(A2,5),EDATE(A2,7))
```

It compares the month of the cell on the left. If the month is June add 5 to get November. If the month is November, add 7 to get June. Drag it to fill the other cells.

[image]